# Difference between Xen hypervisor and Xen server

Tags: xen

Like title suggests...something is not very clear to me.
I am used to virtualbox and vmware, now I'd like to use xen but...I find two different websites, hypervisor and server.
What's the difference?

Moreover I really need TWO phisical machines, one client and one server, to use this hypervisor? Can't I just install both client and server on a machine?

Seems a little tricky to me...

Comment: Are you sure you need bare-metal hypervisor like Xen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was confused too.  I'm scrambling to leave VMWare ESXi baremetal hypervisor for various reasons.. most of which have to do with the lack of configurability in the free/lab version of ESXi.

**XenServer** - XenServer is an enterprise-class, cloud-proven, virtualization platform that delivers all of the critical features needed for any server and datacenter virtualization implementation.

**XenProject** -
See this table for a list of features across differing versions of their hypervisor : http://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Xen_Release_Features

XenProject Hypervisor's getting started :   http://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Getting_Started

> The recommended way for most people to get Xen Project is to install
>   via your distribution wherever possible. There are many distros which
>   have good support for Xen Project included right out of the box....

Different people say differing things..  is XenProject Baremetal?

From : http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showpost.php?p=8374801&postcount=23

> In the case of two commonly used bare metal hypervisors (VMWare and
>   Hyper-V), these are special cases in which both the hypervisor and the
>   special management O/S are provided by the same company. In this case,
>   since the same company provides the entire "stack", they can offer an
>   ISO that installs the lot.
>
> Xen is different - as a previous posted mentioned, it's a "project"
>   rather than a "product" - I'm not sure you understood the point that
>   was being made. Xen is the hypervisor and a set of management tools
>   that run within the special guest O/S (which Xen refers to as "dom0"),
>   but Xen themselves do not supply that operating system themselves. I
>   think there are two reasons for this - 1) There are many other
>   suitable operating systems already in existence, so why re-invent the
>   wheel? and 2) Different people will have different preferences as to
>   which operating system they prefer, so why force them into a single
>   option when you can provide choice?
>
> So, what makes Xen different from other bare metal hypervisors:
>
> Pros:
>   - You have a choice of different operating systems to run for the management layer. This allows people with expertise in various O/S's
>   to choose the most appropriate one and allow them to fine-tune it as
>   appropriate.
>   - This allows Xen to focus on doing a single thing - building a hypervisor and associated tools, without being distracted by building
>   a custom O/S to run with it.
>
> Cons:
>   - There is no single vendor or pre-packaged solution/product that you get with VMWare or Hyper-V. In theory, someone could package up a
>   linux or BSD distro with all the Xen tools into an installable ISO,
>   but the question would be - which O/S and why? Then you'd also have
>   the issue that you'd be combining different packages/distros that may
>   have different licencing or distribution rights, different update
>   mechanisms etc. So, while it's possible to build an installable ISO,
>   it's probably more hassle than it's worth.
>
> So, in summary - if you want a pre-packaged solution that you can
>   install "with my eyes closed" - Xen is probably not your best choice.
>   However, if you want something that can be extensively
>   customised/tweaked and finely tuned then Xen is probably a better
>   choice than VMWare or Hyper-V.
>
> Hope all this makes sense.

In the end do you want to administer Xen Hypervisor with a certain privileged OS? or let Citrix pick for you and get Xen Server?

Sources :

http://www.xenproject.org/developers/teams/hypervisor.html

http://www.xenserver.org/overview-xenserver-open-source-virtualization/open-source-virtualization-features.html

Answer (score 3):

I did some further digging since I was confused myself. According to the [Xenserver.org website](http://xenserver.org/overview-xenserver-open-source-virtualization/source-code.html), the XenServer distribution is based upon:

> XenServer is a Linux distribution that is based on the Xen hypervisor, the Linux kernel, and the CentOS Linux distribution and user tools.